# Create a link in a partial that keeps the parent view's URL parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a view with a partial in it, like this:

```
# my_controller/my_view
The value of the parameter is <%= @parameter %>
<%= render :partial "my_contoller/my_partial", locals: {internal_param: @parameter_for_partial %>

#my_controller/my_partial
<div>
  The value of the internal parameter is <%= internal_param %><br />
  <%= link_to "Link", {:partial_url_param => internal_param + 1} %>
</div>
```

The controller action takes URL parameters:

```
def class MyControllerController < ApplicationController
  def my_action
    @parameter = params[:parent_view_url_param]
    @parameter_for_partial = params[:partial_url_param]
  end
end
```

Now, when I go to `/my_controller/my_view?parent_view_url_param=1&partial_url_param=2`, I get a page that looks like this:

```
The value of the parameter is 1
<div>
  The value of the internal parameter is 2<br />
  <a href="/my_controller/my_view?partial_url_param=3">Link</a>
</div>
```

I want the link to point to `/my_controller/my_view?parent_view_url_param=1&partial_url_param=3`, with all of the URL parameters from the original link the same except the ones that the partial directly overrides. Moreover, if I added more parameters, I would want the link in the partial to keep those as well, without requiring me to make any changes to the partial.

Is there a way to do this in Rails 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
=link_to 'Link', params.merge(partial_url_param: internal_param + 1)
```

Comment: I'm looking at this right now. The one concern I have is that if some sensitive parameters are included, like `authenticity_token`, we should strip those out before doing the merge.

Comment: You could replace `params` with `params.except(sensitive_params)`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the method in bgates' answer, I created this helper method and put it in `application_helper.rb`:

```
  # Creates a link back to the current view, keeping all of
  # the URL parameters the same except some that you
  # change. Also strips out some URL parameters that can
  # have implications for the app's security.
  #
  # Input params:
  # link_name: The text to show for the link
  # original_params: The params hash available to the view
  # params_to_change: A hash in the format of
  #   orignal_params that indicates which URL parameters
  #   to change, and what to change them to
  # html_options (optional): The HTML options to apply
  #   to the link
  #
  # Output: The HTML for a link back to the view with some
  #   of the URL parameters changed, as specified by
  #   the params_to_change hash
  def link_to_with_same_params(link_name, original_params, params_to_change, html_options = {})
    send_params = original_params.deep_dup
    send_params.delete :authenticity_token
    send_params.delete :commit
    send_params.merge! params_to_change
    return link_to link_name, send_params, html_options
  end
```

Which allows me to do this in my example view:

```
#my_controller/my_partial
<div>
  The value of the internal parameter is <%= internal_param %><br />
  <%= link_to_with_same_params "Link", params, {:partial_url_param => internal_param + 1} %>
</div>
```